# ReactJs & simple-react-validator :: Issue with the date validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I am Working on a **ReactJs** project and I use **formik** in it.

I am using **simple-react-validator** for the validation.

I am facing an issue with the date validation in the above library.

Here is the code which I used in my project.

```
<FormGroup >
  <InputMask mask="99-99-9999" name="ActualDate" className="form-control"
    placeholder={DATE_FORMAT_PLACEHOLDER}
    value={values.ActualDate}
    onChange={(e) => {
        setFieldValue("ActualDate", e.target.value);
    }}>
  </InputMask>
  <Label className="impo_label">Date</Label>
  {this.validator.message('date', values.ActualDate && moment(values.ActualDate , 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 
    ['required', {date: values.ActualDate}]
  )}
</FormGroup>
```

I also try with the momentjs format.

```
{this.validator.message('date', values.ActualDate && moment(values.ActualDate , 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 
    ['required', {date: moment(values.ActualDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY', true)}]
)}
```

But this is also not working.

can anyone help me in this?